# Return BigDecimal fields as JSON String values in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, get, bigdecimal

I have a `Get API` which returns a `JSON`. The format expected is:

```
{
   "value1": "123.00",
   "value2": "23.00"
}
```

These values are `BigDecimal` in the object:

```
public class Result{
    BigDecimal value1;
    BigDecimal value2;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Now, when the request is made, I create the `Result` object and populate these values as `BigDecimal`, create a list and return. The response I received is:

```
{
   "value1": 123.00,
   "value2": 23.00
}
```

The values are correct but are not strings. How can I make them strings?

I know we can convert `BigDecimal` to `String` but I have object with BigDecimal fields only and I can't populate String values to it.

Finally, this is how the list is made:

```
List<MyObj> obj = Arrays.stream(myObj).collect(Collectors.toList());

    Result result = new Result();

    obj.forEach(t -> t.mergeToResult(result));  // mergeToResults does all the population like result.setValue1(new BigDecimal(123.00))

    return result;
```

Comment: Are you using some library for json serialization/deserialization?

Comment: can't you create a custom serializer to convert the BigDecimal value to string while  returning the json output?

Comment: No, not using any library.

Comment: @Ankur: Thats the question, how should I do it?

Comment: can you help to add how you serialized `result` object ?

Comment: If you want string - make them Strings and not BigDecimal, if they are numeric follow the valid JSON standard and return them as numbers

Comment: The last part about list and arrays and your collector is unclear and confusing. You have not explained your inputs, outputs, and purpose.

Comment: Consider use a ObjectConverter Codec. See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72143091/how-do-return-a-bigdecimal-as-decimal-in-json-using-jaxrs

Answer (score 7):

You can use `@JsonFormat` annotation as below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

public class Result {        
   @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
   private BigDecimal value;

   // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Use `String`

The `Number` type in JSON is likely to be considered as a [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) number, from my reading of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types,_syntax_and_example), per the traditional behavior of JavaScript. Floating-point technology purposely sacrifices accuracy for the sake of execution speed.

The [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class has exactly the opposite purpose, to sacrifice execution speed for the sake of accuracy.

So, if you want the best chance of preserving your `BigDecimal` value, store as a `String`. Hopefully this approach makes it less likely that the consumer of your JSON will inadvertently parse the incoming value as a floating-point. Clearly document to those people consuming your JSON about your intention to have the data parsed as a `BigDecimal` or equivalent rather than floating-point.

Java export:

```java
String output = myBigDecimal.toString() ;
```

JSON:

```json
{
   "value1": "123.00",
   "value2": "23.00"
}
```

Java import:

```java
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( "123.00" ) ;
```

Study the documentation for [`BigDecimal::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString()) and [`new BigDecimal( string )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(char%5B%5D)). You should also be aware of the [`BigDecimal::toPlainString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()) method.

### Streams

As for your Java streams, I do not understand your issue. You use of `List` and arrays is unexplained.

Basically, you should be implementing a `toJson` method on your `Result` class. Call that `Result::toJson` method within your stream code.

Here is an example of such a class.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Result {

    BigDecimal start, stop;

    public String toJson () {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( "{\n" );
        sb.append( "    " );  // Indent with four spaces.
        sb.append( this.enquote( "start:" ) + " " );
        sb.append( this.enquote( start.toString() ) );
        sb.append( " , \n" );
        sb.append( "    " );  // Indent with four spaces.
        sb.append( this.enquote( "stop:" ) + " " );
        sb.append( this.enquote( stop.toString() ) );
        sb.append( "\n}\n" );
        return sb.toString();
    }

    static public Result fromJson ( String json ) {
         …
    }

    private String enquote ( String string ) {
        return "\"" + string + "\"";
    }

    // Constructor
    public Result ( BigDecimal start , BigDecimal stop ) {
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Result r = new Result( new BigDecimal( "123.00" ) , new BigDecimal( "23.00" ) );
        System.out.println( r.toJson() );
    }
}
```

When run.

```
{
    "start:" "123.00" , 
    "stop:" "23.00"
}
```

## Consider a framework

Tip: You may want to consider using a JSON↔Java mapping framework to help you with this work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring framework, you can configure serialization `BigDecimal -> String` globally like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configOverride(BigDecimal.class)
            .setFormat(JsonFormat.Value.forShape(JsonFormat.Shape.STRING));
    return objectMapper;
}
```